# Can I drag the map with ctrl in Openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Exist a way to drag the map when I hold down the Ctrl (control) key?

Normally to drag the map is necessary just hold the left mouse button and move on the map, but I need to drag the map without hold the left mouse button but with the ctrl button. Is possibile?

Comment: Better use arrows keys otherwise how do you control the panning?

Comment: i want control the panning with the mause. I want only drag the map while I hold Ctrl and not the left mouse button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a way to only allow panning while holding ctrl-key. A fully working example can be found in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnpq3ufe/

For it to work, you have to disable the existing dragPan interaction in your map init to override/re-add it later on:

```
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    dragPan: false
})
```

After that you can create your new customised interaction, which just triggers while ctrl key is pressed, for this we use `condition`, for more information about conditions and its possibilities you can head over to the [OpenLayers APIdocs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.EventsConditionType):

```
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.DragPan({
  condition: function(event) {
    return event.originalEvent.ctrlKey
  }
}));
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is just a proof of concept yet and is not fully working, since it snaps into the wrong place when initially starting the drag. Unfortunately I have no time currently to figure everything out right now, but it could probably still help you to get started. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnpq3ufe/5/
Basically I am using the `pointermove` event to recenter the map each time the cursor is moved while holding the ctrl-key:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(event){
    if(event.originalEvent.ctrlKey){
    var pixelCenter = [map.coordinateToPixelTransform_[4], 
        map.coordinateToPixelTransform_[5]];
    var movedPixels = [pixelCenter[0]-event.pixel[0],
        pixelCenter[1]-event.pixel[1]];
    map.getView().setCenter(map.getCoordinateFromPixel(movedPixels));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this works when i press both Ctrl and the left button of the mouse. I need that it works only when I press Ctrl  and no  the left button of the mouse.

Comment: I am really sorry for the misunderstanding in the beginning, maybe the new proof of concept I added to my answer can help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help me!!